# Enter a number n, then prints all even squares between 1 and n

Tags: java, for-loop

I need help figuring out on how to output even numbers between 1 and N (n is a number entered by the user).

Here is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         int n;
         int i = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Number");
        n = scan.nextInt();

        for(i=1; i<n; i++){
            if(i%2==0)
            i = i*i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }    
    }
}
```

Now that prints out the wrong output. I would like to know how it gets from 4 to 16 and to 36.

Sample Input: `45`

Expected Output:

```
4
16
36
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't update `i` inside the loop. If it's even, just print `i*i`.

Comment: And change the condition to `i*i < n`.

Comment: remove i = i*i , your answer is i only if the condition i%2 == 0. thats the even number. Change i < n to i <= n, to include number n itself.

Comment: Could you please give example input, output, and expected output?

Comment: Please check the edited code @JL2210

Comment: Please don't put the answer in the question. I've suggested an acceptable way to add input/output without breaking the purpose of the question in an edit. Please take a look.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't change the value of `i` inside the for loop. Instead of changing `i` to equal `i*i`, just print out `i*i` using the statement `System.out.println(i*i)`;
Secondly, you also forgot the curly brackets after your if statement.

Comment: why does it output 4,16,36? what's the logic?

Comment: Because you updated the loop variable inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are already increasing the variable `i` in the for definition, you don't need to increase again inside for block. Also start from 2 and move on by adding 2 on each step for a more efficient implementation.

```
for(i=2; i*i<n; i+=2){
        System.out.println(i*i);
    }
```

Comment: @shmosel forgot to delete.